# Where is the Selk crater on Titan with respect to Saturn?

Tags: titan, saturn, dragonfly

The [Dragonfly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragonfly_(spacecraft)) mission to Titan will land at the [Selk crater](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selk_(crater)).  Titan is tidally locked in synchronous rotation with Saturn and I'm trying to find out if Dragonfly will be on the Saturn-facing side of the Moon.  I know that the landing site is at [7° North and 199° West](https://geohack.toolforge.org/geohack.php?pagename=Selk_(crater)&params=7.0_N_199.0_W_globe:titan_type:landmark) but I haven't been able to discover the prime meridian with respect to Saturn.

Comment: Tidally locked moons have their 0° longitude defined as the 'sub-planet' point (In every instance I've seen)

Comment: @BrendanLuke15 I've quoted you here [Just how locked is Titan? Does it exhibit libration due to eccentricity? Have residual oscillations not yet damped out been detected or ruled out?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/57527/12102)

Comment: I came along to accept the answer that was posted here yesterday but it appears to have been deleted‽

Comment: @BrendanLuke15  That seems logical, I wonder if it's standardised by the IAU?

Answer (score 4):

So, after a lot of googling (I hesitate to call it 'research'), I've found the following:

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_meridian#Prime_meridian_on_other_planetary_bodies) states that:

> Titan is the largest moon of Saturn and, like the Earth's moon, always
> has the same face towards Saturn, and so the middle of that face is 0
> longitude.

but has no supporting references.

The IAU Working Group on Cartographic Coordinates and Rotational Elements ([WGCCRE](https://www.iau.org/science/scientific_bodies/working_groups/100/)) has a [responsibility to](https://astrogeology.usgs.gov/groups/IAU-WGCCRE)

> define the rotational elements of the planets, satellites, asteroids,
> and comets of the solar system on a systematic basis and to relate
> their cartographic coordinates rigorously to the rotational elements.

I couldn't find the rules for coordinate systems on the IAU website, but [NASA has a PDS standards reference document](https://pds.nasa.gov/datastandards/pds3/standards/) that, in chapter 2, references the WGCCRE and states:

> If a body has a solid surface, prime meridians for a given longitude
> system may be defined by specifying the coordinates of a surface
> feature on the body (usually a small feature such as a crater in the
> equatorial region) or **by the mean direction relative to the parent
> body for synchronously rotating bodies (e.g., the Moon, the Galilean
> moons, and most of the Saturnian moons).** Where insufficient
> observations exist to determine the principal moment of inertia,
> coordinates of a surface feature will be specified and used to define
> the prime meridian.

(my emphasis)

So at 199° west the Selk crater is on the far side of the moon, as viewed from Saturn.