# Just how locked is Titan? Does it exhibit libration due to eccentricity? Have residual oscillations not yet damped out been detected or ruled out?

Tags: planetary-science, titan, moons, tidal-locking

Under [Where is the Selk crater on Titan with respect to Saturn?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/57522/12102) there is [@BrendanLuke15's comment](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/57522/where-is-the-selk-crater-on-titan-with-respect-to-saturn#comment190215_57522) which provides a helpful hint:

> Tidally locked moons have their 0° longitude defined as the 'sub-planet' point (In every instance I've seen)

The first thing I think of is [libration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libration). (though when I was much younger it was often *libation*).

I've included a libration GIF from [Who does these mesmerizing simulations of the phases of the Moon? And how?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/19936/12102) below to show just how hard it is to try to figure out where the "'sub-planet' point" is here. This is because the Moon's eccentricity is pretty large so that while it rotates once a month *steadily* its rotation around Earth speeds up and slows down in angular velocity by quite a lot.

For more on Earth's moon see:

- [What are the "Moon L, B, C" angles shown in this solar eclipse simulation?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/22375/12102)
- [How to get lunar L, B, C parameters from the Moon's 3x3 rotation matrix from the Python package Skyfield?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/42127/12102)
- [Shape and dimensions of the Moon's reference surface for selenographic latitude/longitude?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/27359/12102) (no accepted answer yet)

And for another tidally locked moon instance that @BL15 may or may not have seen:

- [How "locked" are Pluto and Charon? How much does each librate as seen from the other?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/45342/12102)

**Question:** How tidally locked is Titan? Does it exhibit libration due to eccentricity? Have any residual oscillations not yet damped out been detected or ruled out?

By "ruled out" I mean by direct measurement: more than "we know Titan's been there a long time and made of normal materials and so it must have damped out by now".

---

---

Animation used in [EarthSky.org](http://earthsky.org/moon-phases/new-moon):

[image: the Moon's libration]

[Source](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Lunar_libration_with_phase_Oct_2007.gif) but as pointed out in [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/20564/12102) by the GIF's creator, the original image is actually in [Wikimedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Lunar_libration_with_phase_Oct_2007.gif)

Comment: Obviously there is some libration, as the orbit has some eccentricity. As for residual wobble: that's  *hard* question. Even for our Moon, i could not get an authoritative answer.

Comment: @CuteKItty_pleaseStopBArking   I guess someone at JPL is going have to work it out between now and 2036 so that Dragonfly can land at its target :)

Comment: @DaveGremlin shrug. the residual wobble will be small, and with a period of hundreds to thousands of years. Just observe where it *is* and don't try to predict where it will be in your greatgreatgreatgrandchildren's time.